# Errors from using \MakeLowercase with fmtcount's commands

Tags: memoir, fmtcount

When I try to use `\MakeLowercase` and `fmtcount`'s different number formatting commands I get all kinds of errors. I'm primarily interested in getting rid of the error message from the first version of `\printpartnum`, but would also appreciate help on the other versions.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\MakeLowercase}

\renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{\partnumfont \ordinalstringnum{\thepart}}
% TeX STOPPED: Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 9.

% \renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{\partnumfont \ordinalstring{part}}
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: You can't use `\relax' after \the. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Paragraph ended before \@skipmath was complete. [  \part{Title}]

% \renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{\partnumfont \numberstringnum{\thepart}}
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing number, treated as zero. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing number, treated as zero. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing number, treated as zero. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:9: Missing number, treated as zero. [  \part{Title}]
% TeX STOPPED: Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 9.

% \renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{\partnumfont \numberstring{part}}
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:19: You can't use `\relax' after \the. [  \part{Title}]
% c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls:19: Paragraph ended before \@skipmath was complete. [  \part{Title}]
\begin{document}
  \part{Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just do `\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{\ordinalstring{part}}`. In any case, `\MakeLowercase` is *not* like a font change command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\MakeLowercase` is *not* a font changing command: it takes an argument and tries full expansion on it.

With your first code you are passing `\ordinalstringnum` to `\MakeLowercase` and this is meaningless.

The second attempt has the same flaw: with

```
\renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{\partnumfont \ordinalstring{part}}
```

you're again passing `\ordinalstring` to `\MakeLowercase` and this is wrong.

You just have to do

```
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{\ordinalstring{part}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do I feel stupid… I knew `\MakeLowercase` wasn’t a font changing command. But I guess that I mistakenly extrapolated the memoir manual. In section 6.6 regarding commands such as `\setsecheadstyle` it says “Note that the very last element in the ⟨font⟩ argument may be a macro that takes one argument (the number and title of the heading).” Apparently this doesn’t apply to `\partnumfont`…